# Which inbuilt Sitecore roles give access to the "Clones" panel in the configuration menu?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I thought it would be Sitecore Client Configuring, but apparently not.

EDIT:
Following Yan's input I've looked at the Application > Content Editor > Ribbons > Strips > Configure > Item Clones security settings and my user role should be able to read the clone panel, through membership of the client authoring role. I've also explicitly given the role access to read and write there. Still no joy. I've tested by removing access to presentation and templates, and that works fine for removing panels, so I've got the right role and user and I'm setting security in the right place.

Unless anyone has a better idea this is looking like a support ticket...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify this yourself using AccessViewer tool: switch to the 'core' database, open AccessViewer, navigate to Application > Content Editor > Ribbons > Strips > Configure > Item Clones and see what it has for various built-in roles. You'll have to select those roles one by one and see how security settings change.

At least, I can see the Client Authoring and Client Designing have read access...

I might be mistaken in details, but you should get the idea ;-)

UPDATE: Also, check Application > Content Editor > Ribbons > Chunks > Item Clones path, which hold the actual buttons definitions.

Comment: Client Authoring definitely does have read access, but my user role is a member of Client Authoring and still doesn't get to see it... Puzzled.

Comment: If your user is a member of another role, and it is explicitly denied to read that item, the effective permission will be denied (because I suspect 'allow' on 'Item Clones' is a result of inherited 'allow' from upper item)...  Anyway, see what AccessViewer says for your user, not only for Client Authoring

Comment: Have checked it with the actual user as well as the roles. There are no explicit denies by role or user, so no conflict. I also notice I can't add cloning buttons to the customised panel for that user, they just aren't there to select. This looking very much like a support ticket...

Comment: ´Application > Content Editor > Ribbons > Chunks > Item Clones´ seems to have been the culprit. I'm not sure why both Chunks/Item Clones and Strips/Configure/Item Clones need to have access granted.

Comment: Think I've got it now. Strips/Configure/Item Clones is just a blank space to put some buttons, while Chunks/Item Clones holds the items the buttons are rendered from. Every day an education :-) Thanks Yan, can you add the Chunks bit to your answer so I can accept it?